# Windows application on Nvidia TX2?

Tags: c++, gdi+, nvidia, cntk

I have code developed for windows 10 ( C++, GDI+, CNTK) that I wish to run on Nvidia TX2.  Is it possible?  Or must port to Linux?

Comment: What do you want to run on your Nvidia TX2?

Comment: Windows is not supported by Jetson TX-2. You must port your code to Embedded Ubuntu `aarch64` architecture.

Comment: If you are using the the devkit Jetson TX-2 you have to port your code. As I understand, the only OS's available for TX-2 are Linux distributions.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the necessity to use `TX-2` you have to port your software - [LINK](https://developer.nvidia.com/embedded/jetpack). As the link shows, `JetPack` for the `TX-2` includes a Linux image only.

If there is a why to use another hardware system, you can use a graphics card of your choice. Then you can use `CUDA` for Nvidia, `ROC` for AMD or `openCL`.